# Compare similar training files with Test File and give Result in Maching percentage _Machine Learning Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have 5 Images as Baseline and they are of same size and content. You can say little bit variation but altogether similar.

Now I have a Test image which can be same as of those 5 images or can be different .
I wanted to get How much percentage my Test Image is matching with baseline images.

Baseline Images will be in Train folder and 1 test Image in test folder.

How can I achieve this with Machine Learning so I can use for large files later.

Tensorflow, Scikitlern, Scikit images which One will be good. ?
I will appreciate if you could give me demo code if you can ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you could achieve this by using convolucional neural networks (CNN). However, you would need much more images than 5. You could use the [Keras library](https://keras.io/) (see Doc's), which uses either `TensorFlow` or `Theano` backends.

In Keras documentation you find this example that shows how to pre-process your data from folders, as you mentioned. Then, you just need to fit it to your your CNN model, which you can also find how to implement it in Keras docs.

(Usually follows the structure: `Convolution Layer -> MaxPooling -> Flatten -> Neural Network`) :

**Example of using** `.flow_from_directory(directory)`**:**

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

If you prefer an approach with GUI perhaps you could try the [Orange](https://blog.biolab.si/) software, which offer Data Mining/Machine Learning features with an user interface. They have a blog and some youtube videos that you could watch for further information.